# Reaproveitamento de código com linguagem web

Tags: javascript, html, css, herança, biblioteca

Estou trabalhando em três **aplicativos** diferentes que usam **Ionic e Cordova**.
Os três são bem semelhantes em alguns pontos principalmente no layout.

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma especie de **biblioteca** ou algo que eu modifique apenas uma vez o código e replique para os três projetos, como **herança** em algumas outras linguagens.

Se alguém souber como se chama isto ou tem algum material ou conhecimento por favor compartilhe.

> OBS: As linguagens que uso são JavaScript, HTML e CSS.

Comment: Você pode criar uma `task` com gulp, grunt, etc. Eu escolheria um dos 3 projetos e de seu `src` pegaria os arquivos para replicar nos outros projetos.

Answer (score 2):

O nome do que voce quer é Web Components (https://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/)

Aqui tem uma introdução em português sobre:
http://tableless.com.br/web-components-introducao/

Pode ser feito com JS puro ou com bibliotecas JS como Polymer

Comment: Recomendo fortemente usar Polymer!